# export of scraping data to csv

Tags: python, web-scraping, export-to-csv

New in python, I scraped a site to get data like season, teams and position.
I want to save the data in a CSV.
The problem is that the data all get listed on one line.
[image: current release]

I would like to have a result like this:
[image: what i would like]

Below my code:

```
import pdb
import re
import os
import json
import pandas as pd

'''Structurer les données dans un taleur'''

Base=[]
Saison=[]
Position=[]
Equipe=[]

for ele in os.listdir('Data/Saison'):
    with open('Data/Saison/'+ele,'r',encoding='utf8') as output:
        contenu = output.read()

    saison=ele.replace('.html','')
    Saison.append(saison) 
    
    pattern='<td class="left first__left strong">(.{1,8})</td>'
    position=re.findall(pattern,contenu)
    Position.append(position)
    
    
    pattern='<a class="list-team-entry" href="/fr/basketball/equipe/(.{1,4})'
    id_equipe=re.findall(pattern,contenu)
    
    
    pattern='<a class="list-team-entry" href="/fr/basketball/equipe/(.{1,30})" title="(.{1,20})">'
    ens=re.findall(pattern,contenu)
    for e in ens:
        equipe=e[1]
        Equipe.append(equipe)
        

    pattern='<td class="left highlight">(.{1,8})</td>'
    pourcent_victoire=re.findall(pattern,contenu)

        
Base.append([Saison,Position,Equipe])
'''On enregistre en CSV'''
df=pd.DataFrame(Base, columns = ['saison','position','equipe'])
df.to_csv('DataFinal/Base.csv',sep='|',encoding='utf8',index=False)
```

`
Thanks for you help

Comment: Hey, Nadia! Welcome to SO! Maybe all you need to do to create your frame is `df=pd.DataFrame([Saison,Position,Equipe], columns = ['saison','position','equipe'])`?

Comment: Hey, Unfortunately no, it doesn't work. With your code I have this error: "AssertionError: 3 columns passed, passed data had 189 columns".

Comment: Sorry, this completely slipped through cracks but maybe this is still relevant. Not sure how I can help though, but did you try inspecting how individual lists you use look like? Is it possible that `Base` has more content than what your example shows? It looks like an empty list before you append elements to it, but it could be not in the final application.